# Split UICollectionView & UICollectionViewDataSource shows black screen

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm starting a new project with a collection view that will be downloading a lot of data from a REST api. I've split the collection view and datasource into two files, but when I run the application, all I get is a black screen. I've seen a few questions and tried changing the background, adding the collection view as a subview, and nothing seems to be working. I don't run into any errors and the debug view hierarchy and the views are listed (back to front) as UIWindoW -> MainSearchVC -> UICollectionView.

I originally thought no cells were being filled in, but they should be since I set a UIImage in the cells. I'm not sure where else to look for this. My code is below -  if anyone has experience with splitting the collection view from it's datasource or why things aren't working, please help:)

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = MainSearchVC()

    return true
    }
}

class MainSearchVC:  UICollectionViewController {
    init(){
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        self.collectionView?.dataSource = MainSearchDataSource()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        collectionView?.register(ImageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "imagecell")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.collectionView?.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        NSLog("Visible Cells: " + String(describing: self.collectionView?.visibleCells.count))
        self.view.addSubview(self.collectionView!)
    }
}

class MainSearchDataSource: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imagecell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return cell
    }
}

class ImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "SR71")
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return iv
    }()

    func setupViews(){
        addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.width)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your `MainSearchVC` collection view `dataSource` delegate

First you should understand the **`Zeroing Weak Reference`**

`dataSource` delegate is maintaining a `weak` reference to your `Object` of `MainSearchDataSource`. And your statement is

`self.collectionView?.dataSource = MainSearchDataSource()`

Just allocated and assigned. **It will not retain the datasource object**.

You have to create a `class variable` and assign the `MainSearchDataSource` object. It will hold the object reference until `MainSearchVC` deallocate from memory.

```
class MainSearchVC:  UICollectionViewController {

   var searchDataSource: MainSearchDataSource?

    init(){

        super.init(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame,  collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

        searchDataSource = MainSearchDataSource()
        self.collectionView?.dataSource = searchDataSource

    }

    // Remaining code of your `MainSearchVC`
}
```

Comment: Ah, is that a standard rule? System frameworks don't keep a strong reference to any classes if you initialize on assignment?

Comment: No.. only delegate object not retained because it's weak.